# Merge array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array as follow:

In this there are same brand id having more than one product,I want to merge same brand id into one array and have product array inside brand.As example

Any suggestion on this.

Thanks.

Comment: There are ***thousands*** of questions/answers out there about merging PHP arrays. Yours is certainly not the first of it's kind. **Try something**.

Comment: What's your budget? If you want us to do all the work you can't expect it to be free, right?

Comment: This is not even a valid PHP code - strings should be in quotes. Also, have you ever heard about code formatting? Imagine yourself that the code placeholder on SO is not super wide. And there is a reason - line of code should not exceed 80 characters! Otherwise it's hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new array with brand_id as array key:

```
$res = array();
foreach ($array as $row) {
  if (!isset($res[$row['brand_id']])) {
    $res[$row['brand_id']] = array(
      'brand_logo' => $row['brand_logo'],
      'brand_discovered_count' => $row['brand_discovered_count'],
      'brand_name' => $row['brand_name'],
      'brand_template_id' => $row['brand_template_id'],
      'products' => array()
    );
  }
  $res[$row['brand_id']]['products'][] = array(
    'product_id' => $row['product_id'],
    'product_price' => $row['product_price']
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and valuable time